# metal, meddle, mettle, medal pronunciation in American English

Tags: pronunciation, north-american-english, flapping

Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary of Current English has the following phonetic symbols:

**meddle**

> / ˈmedl; ˋmɛdl/

**medal**

> / ˈmedl; ˋmɛdl/

**mettle**

> / ˈmetl; ˋmɛtl/

**metal**

> / ˈmetl; ˋmɛtl/

Oxford gives British English usages; in BrE, meddle and medal are pronounced the same and mettle and metal are the same too.

---

I know that in AmE, *t* is usually pronounced as *d*.

Then how are  **metal**  and **mettle** pronounced?

Are they pronounced exactly the same as  **medal**  and **meddle** in AmE?

---

Adding to my confusion: please look at how they are pronounced in Merriam-Webster.

**meddle**

> Pronunciation:     'me-dəl

**medal**

> Pronunciation:     'me-dəl

**mettle**

> Pronunciation:     'me-təl

**metal**

> Pronunciation:     'me-təl

Comment: The only way of distinguishing *medal* and *metal* in American English is that the /ɛ/ might be shorter in *metal*. This is not very reliable; it works reasonably well for longer vowels, but for shorter vowels (especially /ɪ/) this length difference is very hard to hear.

Comment: Most people in the US will pronounce the two words nearly identically, unless in a context where it's important to distinguish them.  Probably you could use a sound analyzer to detect a difference, but most people wouldn't hear it.

Comment: Your addition of reasonable research makes this a valid ELU question. It is worrying that US-based dictionaries (not just M-W) use the t instead of the d in their pronunciation guides when there's no t sound.

Answer (score 4):

Both words are typically pronounced [ˈmɛɾl̩] with a [voiced alveolar flap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_flaps#Alveolar).

That [ɾ] which I've written there is one of several possible phonetic allophones of both the /t/ and /d/ phonemes, but doesn’t sound quite like either [t] or [d] would there. It’s a very [light, quick tap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping) — such as you might find in the middle of the Italian (or Spanish or Portuguese) word *cara*.

Spelling is immaterial here: all four of *medal, meddle, metal, mettle* typically have that same pronunciation in most speakers at normal conversation rates.

Comment: Note that Americans don't actually pronounce it with a /d/. If you pronounce *metal* with a /d/, you risk being misunderstood (depending on exactly how you pronounce your /d/s).

Comment: @PeterShor Right, the [ɾ] is an allophone of both /t/ and /d/ but doesn't sound quite like either [t] or [d]. I should have made that clearer.

Comment: Actually, I think in this particular context, a plosive realization like [d], with lateral release (i.e. [dˡ]) is in fact possible. See Mark Liberman's Language Log post [Metal v. medal](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=8697). @PeterShor's point that this might not be identical to the realization of phonemic /d/ is valid, but it might be indistinguishable.

Comment: @sumelic interesting link... So the  m words in 'Don't *mettle* with the *metal/medal*'  are not pronounced the same in AmE?

Comment: @Clare: some speakers might distinguish them, but Liberman does say "It's true that for most Americans, these words are homophones". I can't hear any difference.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth . It might also be considered that the answer given is opinion, the citation of sources irrelevant to establishing a fact.. The answer does not establish by reference that the 4 words in question are homophones in any variety of English.

Comment: If the 'mandative subjunctive' should be chosen for reasons of  disambiguation, ....

Comment: The "t-flap" dies not occur throughout the whole of America and is present in other varieties of English. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping